# Determine the requested content type?

Tags: django, django-views

I'd like to write a Django view which serves out variant content based on what's requested. For example, for "text/xml", serve XML, for "text/json", serve JSON, etc. Is there a way to determine this from a request object? Something like this would be awesome:

```
def process(request):
    if request.type == "text/xml":
        pass
    elif request.type == "text/json":
        pass
    else:
        pass
```

Is there a property on `HttpRequest` for this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`HttpRequest.META`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META), more specifically `HttpRequest.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT')` — and not <strike>`HttpRequest.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE')`</strike> as mentioned earlier

Comment: I know this is old, but although this is the accepted answer, it is not correct.  As is mentioned in Jan's comment below, the correct method is the 'Accept' header, accessible via `HttpRequest.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT')`.

Comment: You could do a fallback, to handle both cases (plus a default): `request.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT', request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/your_default'))`

Comment: I don't know if something has changed but I seem to have to write: `request.META.get('headers').get("HTTP_ACCEPT")`

Comment: as of 2020 you can use `HttpRequest.content_type`

Answer (score 21):

'Content-Type' header indicates media type send in the HTTP request. This is used for requests that have a content (POST, PUT).

'Content-Type' should not be used to indicate preferred response format, 'Accept' header serves this purpose. To access it in Django use: `HttpRequest.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT')`

[See more detailed description of these headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Answer (score 5):

As said in other answers, this information is located in the `Accept` request header. Available in the request as `HttpRequest.META['HTTP_ACCEPT']`.

However there is no only one requested content type, and this header often is a list of accepted/preferred content types. This list might be a bit annoying to exploit properly. Here is a function that does the job:

```
import re

def get_accepted_content_types(request):
    def qualify(x):
        parts = x.split(';', 1)
        if len(parts) == 2:
            match = re.match(r'(^|;)q=(0(\.\d{,3})?|1(\.0{,3})?)(;|$)',
                             parts[1])
            if match:
                return parts[0], float(match.group(2))
        return parts[0], 1

    raw_content_types = request.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT', '*/*').split(',')
    qualified_content_types = map(qualify, raw_content_types)
    return (x[0] for x in sorted(qualified_content_types,
                                 key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
```

For instance, if `request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT']` is equal to `"text/html;q=0.9,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.7"`. This will return: `['application/xhtml+xml', 'text/html', 'application/xml', '*/*']` *(not actually, since it returns a generator)*.

Then you can iterate over the resulting list to select the first content type you know how to respond properly.

Note that this function should work for most cases but do not handle cases such as `q=0` which means "Not acceptable".

Sources: [HTTP Accept header specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1) and [Quality Values specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.9)

Comment: This answer should replace the top and accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

in django 1.10, you can now use, `request.content_type`, as mentioned here in [their doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.content_type)

Comment: This returns the 'Content-Type' and not the 'Accept' header.

Answer (score 1):

As of Django 3.1, there is the [`HttpRequest.accepts(mime_type)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.accepts) method which determines whether a particular content type is acceptable by the client.

There is a useful [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#content-negotiation-example) linked by that documentation which shows how a `CreateView` could support JSON responses:

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from myapp.models import Author


class JsonableResponseMixin:
    """
    Mixin to add JSON support to a form.
    Must be used with an object-based FormView (e.g. CreateView)
    """

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        response = super().form_invalid(form)
        if self.request.accepts("text/html"):
            return response
        else:
            return JsonResponse(form.errors, status=400)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # We make sure to call the parent's form_valid() method because
        # it might do some processing (in the case of CreateView, it will
        # call form.save() for example).
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        if self.request.accepts("text/html"):
            return response
        else:
            data = {
                "pk": self.object.pk,
            }
            return JsonResponse(data)


class AuthorCreateView(JsonableResponseMixin, CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ["name"]
```