# Django Model store image file size

Tags: django, django-models

I am using Django 1.6. I have a model for uploading image files that looks like this.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path,
                             null=True,
                             blank=True,
                             height_field = 'height',
                             width_field = 'width',
                             verbose_name='Image')
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    width = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    size = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    format = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=255)


    def clean(self):
        self.size = self.url.size

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'image'
```

As you can see, I am storing the size of the image when the `clean()` method is called. This works for what I want to do, but is this best practise? Is there a better way to automatically save the image's file size when saving?

The second part of my question is how can I get the content type as well?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

Model.clean() should be used for validation - do not use it to update/save the data, but rather use it to correct any invalid data (or throw an exception/error message).

You may want to consider not even storing the size of the image in the database, given that you can access it from the ImageField - it eliminates the possibility of the data becoming inconsistent as it changes over time.

I believe this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853581/django-get-uploaded-file-type-mimetype) should address your second question.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question 
Check out the Python Imaging Library PIL on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032642/how-to-obtain-image-size-using-standard-python-class-without-using-external-lib) thread.

```
from PIL import Image
im=Image.open(filepath)
im.size # (width,height) tuple
```

For the second question 
`HttpRequest.META`, more specifically `HttpRequest.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE')`
from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459881/determine-the-requested-content-type) thread